# Trying to loop through different polygons, and find the points within those polygons

Tags: python, geopandas, r-tree

I have 2 datasets:

admin_area.shp - contains  polygon district data which has index, names, geometry
point_data.shp - contains point data which has index, lat, lon, geometry

I want to loop through each polygon within admin_area, then for each area identify if any of my points intersect with that polygon.

I've tried this:

```
# initialise an instance of an rtree Index object
idx = Index()

# loop through each row in the district dataset and extract the geometry of each one
for id, district in admin_areas.iterrows():
    idx.insert(id, district.geometry.bounds)
    
    # loop through each row in the point dataset and load into the spatial index
    for id, point in point_data.iterrows():
        idx.insert(id, point.geometry.bounds)
    
    # get the polygon of each district
    polygon = admin_areas.geometry.iloc[0]

    # how many rows are we starting with?
    print(f"boundaries: {len(admin_areas.index)}")

    # get the indexes of points that intersect bounds of the admin_areas
    possible_matches_index = list(idx.intersection(polygon.bounds))

    # use those indexes to extract the possible matches from the GeoDataFrame
    possible_matches = point_data.iloc[possible_matches_index]
    
    # how many points intersect the area? 
    print(f"Filtered points: {len(possible_matches.index)}")

    # then search the possible matches for precise matches using the slower but more precise method
    precise_matches = possible_matches.loc[possible_matches.within(polygon)]
    print(precise_matches.geometry)

    # how many points itersect the area now?
    print(f"precise points: {len(precise_matches.index)}")
```

It's resulted in this:

```
boundaries: 9
Filtered points: 111
647    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
194    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
21     POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
189    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
640    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
             
973    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
982    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
989    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
990    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
995    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
Name: geometry, Length: 110, dtype: geometry
precise points: 110
boundaries: 9
Filtered points: 222
188    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
214    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
245    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
246    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
252    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
             
973    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
982    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
989    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
990    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
995    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
Name: geometry, Length: 220, dtype: geometry
precise points: 220
boundaries: 9
```

```
boundaries: 9
Filtered points: 111
647    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
194    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
21     POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
189    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
640    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
             
973    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
982    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
989    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
990    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
995    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
Name: geometry, Length: 110, dtype: geometry
precise points: 110
boundaries: 9
Filtered points: 222
188    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
214    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
245    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
246    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
252    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
             
973    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
982    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
989    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
990    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
995    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
Name: geometry, Length: 220, dtype: geometry
precise points: 220
boundaries: 9
```

```
boundaries: 9
Filtered points: 111
647    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
194    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
21     POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
189    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
640    POINT (371053.697 410002.844)
             
973    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
982    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
989    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
990    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
995    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
Name: geometry, Length: 110, dtype: geometry
precise points: 110
boundaries: 9
Filtered points: 222
188    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
214    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
245    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
246    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
252    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
             
973    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
982    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
989    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
990    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
995    POINT (371848.442 409174.713)
Name: geometry, Length: 220, dtype: geometry
precise points: 220
boundaries: 9
```

where it seems to be replicated for just one district, but i want it to go through each district. Does anyone know why? Thank you

Comment: Aren't you using the same polygon for every iteration with `polygon = admin_areas.geometry.iloc[0]`?

Comment: ah yes that makes sense, [0] would choose the first one every time...but removing it did not seem to remedy what I was trying to do